# Problem displaying uppercase "I" in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

It seems that Mathematica reserves the capital i, `I`, for the imaginary unit. I have the following expression:

```
expr = a.b + II
```

For the user, I want to display the above expression with just `I` (for readability, it represents the inertia tensor). So I do:

```
Print[ToString[ReplaceAll[expr, II -> I] // TraditionalForm]]
```

But I still get the "imaginary unit" and not an actual capital i:

[image]

How do I display a capital i? Thanks! To emphasize: this is just to display to the user in a string output, in the actual code I use II...

Comment: Convert to string first, then use `StringReplace`?

Comment: If you can be sure not to confuse yourself, `\[CapitalIota]` could be used directly: `a.b + \[CapitalIota]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve customized display forms, you use either [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) or [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html). Converting to string is usually a measure of last resort, and not what I would recommend here.

Instead, just do this:

```
expr = a.b + II

(* ==> II + a.b *)

II /: MakeBoxes[II, StandardForm] := RowBox[{"I"}]

expr = a.b + II

(* ==> I + a.b *)
```

**Edit: TraditionalForm, String output**

In `MakeBoxes`, the second argument can also be a blank pattern to allow the output `I` not only in `StandardForm`, as I did above:

```
II /: MakeBoxes[II, _] := RowBox[{"I"}]
```

Then, you can for example get this somewhat prettier output:

```
TraditionalForm[a.b + II]
```

> $a.b+I$

or also this string representation, if desired:

```
ToString[a.b + II, TraditionalForm]
```

> $\tt a.b+I$

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = a.b + II;
II2I[n_] := StringReplace[ToString[n], "II" -> "I"];
II2I[expr]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are only doing this for printing then you can simply replace II with "I"

```
Print[ToString[ReplaceAll[expr, II -> "I"] // TraditionalForm]]
(* a.b + I *)
```